# Communication - Saying "Draw"

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel

My opponent was in his second main phase, sitting silently for about a minute. He finally gestured towards me and said, "Draw." I drew. My opponent then shouted, "Judge!" and told the judge that I drew a card on his turn. The judge listened to my side of the story. The judge asked, "Did the card that you drew touch your hand?". I said, "Yes." The judge subsequently gave me a game loss for drawing an extra card.

This occurred at a Competitive REL Standard event in late February of 2014. I did not appeal the ruling with the floor judge. I should have, but I was in shock and there was so much blood rushing to my head that I wasn't thinking clearly.

Should I have been given a game loss for drawing? Does "Draw." constitute a shortcut for "I would like to pass all priority until the next Draw step"?

Comment: What was your opponent's side of why he said "draw"? I'm confused; do you think he said "draw" on purpose to trick you into an infraction, or did he have some other meaning/reason behind saying "draw"?

Comment: @Gendolkari I think he said "Draw" specifically to trick me. He was playing the typical (for February of 2014) G/R Monsters deck, which does not have a way to draw unless they +1 Domri Rade, and Domri was not on the field. I have no way to objectively determine what his intent was, and I am biased because it cost me a match. I could have misunderstood both his word and his gesture.

Comment: did the judge not ask him to explain what he meant by "Draw"? I would have thought that would be an obvious question to ask. He'd either have to say "I meant to pass priority until his next draw step", or "I just said it in hopes that he would draw even though I wasn't passing priority, to win on a technicality"... in either case, you wouldn't lose; in the second case, he would probably be given a warning at the least.

Comment: @Gendolkari The judge didn't ask what he meant.

Comment: that just seems like bad judging... whether the final outcome was correct or not; I'd have to think that the correct first action is to get each person's side of the story... at least ask your opponent if what you said about him saying "draw" was true or not. Very strange.

Comment: I agree, from the information given here, the judge seems to have decided prematurely and without the proper investigation process. You should try to get in touch with said judge, remind him of the case, ask what his reasoning was and give him the opportunity to understand his mistake without making him look or feel stupid. Judges are also just human beings after all, they make mistakes and hate to admit it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rules are not definitively on your side but you definitely should have appealed the ruling. According to the [MTG Infraction Procedure Guide](http://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Infraction_Procedure_Guide_PDF2.pdf) section 2.3, the default penalty for drawing an extra card is a game loss. However, it also says:

> If the player received confirmation from his or her opponent before drawing the card (including confirming the number of cards when greater than one), the infraction is not Drawing Extra Cards.

and your opponent's saying "Draw" and pointing to you arguably counts as confirmation that you should draw for your next turn. This argument might be difficult to make though because "Draw" is not listed explicitly in the [Tournament Rules](http://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Tournament_Rules_PDF2.pdf) list of shortcuts (section 4.2) for passing priority until your opponent's turn.

However, there is another argument to be made that you should not have lost. The Infraction Procedure Guide Drawing Extra Cards section says

> A player illegally puts one or more cards into his or her hand and, at the moment before he or she began the instruction or action that put a card into his or her hand, **no other Game Play Error or *Communication Policy Violation* had been committed**.

One relevant piece of free information (as specified in section 4.1 of the Tournament Rules) is "The current step and/or phase and which player(s) are active", and the Infraction Procedure guide says in the Communication Policy Violation section:

> Players may not represent derived or free information incorrectly

I would argue that your opponent did just that when they said "Draw", which means that the judge should have followed the procedure in this section instead:

> If the situation is simple enough to safely back up without too much disruption to the course of the game, the judge may get permission from the Head Judge to back up the game to the point of the incorrect information. Each action taken is undone until the game reaches the point immediately prior to the error. **Cards incorrectly placed in hand are returned to the location in the zone from which they were moved (if the identity of the incorrectly drawn card is not known to all players, a random card is returned instead)**. Once the game is backed up, it continues from that point.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of someone saying "Draw" to mean the same thing as "pass turn" or the like.

It is typically used as confirmation that you will be drawing a card. For example, one might say "Draw" after casting a card draw spell, for example "Draw 2" while resolving Divination. This is to protect yourself from receiving a game loss if you are somehow mistaken about the amount of cards you should be drawing (or whether you should be drawing) since, as another answer posted:

> If the player received confirmation from his or her opponent before drawing the card (including confirming the number of cards when greater than one), the infraction is not Drawing Extra Cards.

Your opponent then has the opportunity to correct your mistake, whereas if you just drew you might draw the wrong number of cards.

"Draw" is also commonly used during upkeep to mean "go to my draw step".

The important distinction in all of these cases is that the player saying "draw" is confirming that HE will be the one drawing.

Comment: Re "I have never heard of someone saying 'Draw' to mean the same thing as "pass turn" or the like." That's because it doesn't mean that. See my earlier answer.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, your answer was correct and very good! I just wanted to provide some context as to why someone might say "draw".

Comment: I was just commenting on the part I quoted, not the answer in general. You've indeed provided some useful info.

Answer (score 2):

[ Just answering the question that hasn't been answered yet. ]

> Does "Draw." constitute a shortcut for "I would like to pass all priority until the next Draw step"?

No. Not unless you and the other players had previously come to an agreement.

The following are the officially recognized shortcuts according to the Tournament Rules:

> Certain conventional tournament shortcuts used in Magic are detailed below. If a player wishes to deviate from these, he or she should be explicit about doing so. Note that some of these are exceptions to the policy above in that they do cause non-explicit priority passes.
>
> - The statement "Go" (and equivalents such as "Your turn" and "Done") offers to keep passing priority until an opponent has priority in the end step. Opponents are assumed to be acting then unless they specify otherwise.
> - A statement such as "I'm ready for combat" or "Declare attackers?" offers to keep passing priority until an opponent has priority in the beginning of combat step. Opponents are assumed to be acting then unless they specify otherwise.
> - Whenever a player adds an object to the stack, he or she is assumed to be passing priority unless he or she explicitly announces that he or she intends to retain it. If he or she adds a group of objects to the stack without explicitly retaining priority and a player wishes to take an action at a point in the middle, the actions should be reversed up to that point.
> - "No attacks" or similar statements by the active player during combat offers to pass priority until an opponent has priority in the end of combat step.
> - If a player casts a spell or activates an ability with X in its mana cost without specifying the value of X, it is assumed to be for all mana currently available in his or her pool.
> - If a player casts a spell or activates an ability and announces choices for it that are not normally made until resolution, the player must adhere to those choices unless an opponent responds to that spell or ability. If an opponent inquires about choices made during resolution, that player is assumed to be passing priority and allowing that spell or ability to resolve.
> - A player is assumed to have paid any cost of 0 unless he or she announces otherwise.
> - A player who casts a spell or activates an ability that targets an object on the stack is assumed to target the legal target closest to the top of the stack unless the player specifies otherwise.
> - A player is assumed to be attacking another player and not any planeswalkers that player may control unless the attacking player specifies otherwise.
> - A player who chooses a planeswalker as the target of a spell or ability that would deal damage is assumed to be targeting the planeswalker’s controller and redirecting the damage on resolution. The player must adhere to that choice unless an opponent responds.
> - In the Two-Headed Giant format, attacking creatures are assumed to be assigning combat damage to the defending team's primary head, unless the creature's controller specifies otherwise.

Comment: I would think that "Draw" fits within "equivalents such as 'your turn'..."

Comment: @Gendolkari, Look where that shortcut ends. Drawing would be illegal there too.